# image as value in hidden input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, input

I am trying to have an image as value in a hidden input field which I want to use in my javascript.

```
<input type="hidden" class="anything" value="i need an image here" />
```

then I want to use it in a javascript file like

```
$(".anything").val()
```

How can I accomplish this ? Any help'll be great.

Comment: Do you mean image data or image src?

Comment: Where does the image come from, and what are you trying to achieve? You could store the image as a base64 encoded string, but it sounds to me like you're going about this the wrong way...

Answer (score 1):

you can make a div with a class img and give it a property display:none and can call it using jquery.

```
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>
     <div class="img" style="display:none";><img src="adress"> </div>
        <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
          $(.img).fadeIn(1000);
            });
        </script>
     </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".anything").val()` cannot be an image because `.val()` return a String and an image is an DOM object.

You will need at least a conversion from string to a DOM event.

The two main ways to do are :

- the value contains the url of the image instead of the image then you can get the image with : `$("<img>").attr("src", $(".anything").val())`
- you can user base64 data but as Dave Salomon say it's probably not a good ideal

Answer (score -1):

You could possibly write the imagesrc as a string in the value like:

```
$(".anything").val("/path/to/image.png")
```

Or which part of the image do you want as value in the input field?